# Поменять ссылку на изображение

Tags: javascript, html, img

Есть такой код:

```
<html>
<img id="photo" src="car.jpeg" width="200px" height="300px"/> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = document.getElementById("photo");
    a.src = "human.jpeg";
</script>
</html>
```

Если я правильно прочитала и поняла статью об этом, то картинка "car" где допустим изображен автомобиль, должна была поменяться на картинку "human" где изображен человек. Написав этот код, никаких изменений с картинкой не было. Я наверное не до конца поняла как это работает? Или же имеется ошибка в коде? Если это так, прошу вас "пролить" свет на эту тему

Comment: Код выглядит правильно,  есть какие-то ошибки в консоли?

Comment: Вроде никаких ошибок нет, только что проверила. Но картинка с автомобилем, всё так же не меняется на другую...

Comment: а можете код разместить на какой-нибудь онлайн площадке? codeopen или jsbin? Ваш код выглядит правильно, либо путь к картинке не правильный, либо вы что-то не договариваете))))

Comment: Да, конечно, с этим никаких проблем нет)

Comment: тогда выложите код на https://jsbin.com/?html,output например, посмотрим там))) но кажется, вы как-то не правильно запускаете страницу, где ее открываете?

Comment: а какую картинку вы видите? `human` или `car`?

Comment: Car, а ведь должно было видно human?) Или нет? Ведь в js я поменяла её на human..

Comment: Сейчас нет возможности подойти к компьютеру, код обязательно выложу позже.

Comment: да, все правильно говорите

Comment: Я писала JS код в отдельном файле. Когда вставила скрипт в файл с html кодом, всё заработало...Ошибочно прописала путь к файлу, подумала я, что бы проверить, в js файле написала простую функцию "alert()" - Оно заработало, а вот штука с картинкой нет... Но это уже малось, разберусь))

Answer (score 1):

Работает

```js
var a = document.getElementById("photo");
a.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/firmd.jpg";
```

```html
<img id="photo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J3yX.jpg" width="200px" height="300px" />
```

Видимо, ошибка в чём-то другом.